# Minimum term/doc frequency for Seeded Latent Dirichlet Allocation:?

Tags: r, nlp, text-classification, lda, cran

I'm a newbie at language technology using R's `seededlda` package to perform SLDA on a document term matrix created from a corpus of ~400k texts (scientific abstracts) to classify each document into one of two categories, say category "A" and "B".

I get wildly different results based on how I shorten the document term matrix. I first decided to limit the DTM to words used at least 1,000 times in 10,000 different documents. This got me some weird results on the distribution of categories across documents--based on my knowledge of the problem I'm studying, I was expecting category A to outweigh B at least 1.5:1, if not 2:1 or greater. Instead, Category B outweighed A 3:1.

However, if I do not impose any limits on term and document frequency, I get results that align with my prior expectations. Since I'm not a computational linguist, I'm not sure which "approach" is more desirable.

**Is there any literature out there on "optimal" minimum document/term frequency when performing (seeded) LDA?** On a quick Google search, I haven't seem to find anything that would help me decide which of my results are closer to the "correct" answer, or what the threshold should be for cutting terms by document or term frequency.

Comment: First, it would be best to ask on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ since this is not a programming question. Short answer: there is probably no particular recommendation about an optimal ratio in the literature, LDA-based methods (like many NLP methods) are tuned by trial and error and/or some external evaluation method if any is available. However I would say that a threshold of 1000/10000 looks extremely high to me, I would expect that it removes way too many words so that many documents lose their meaning.

Comment: But also I'm surprised that you're apparently considering specific categories A and B: unsupervised methods rarely result in whatever categories are expected, normally this case points to classification (and it's not because one doesn't have annotated data that unsupervised clustering is the answer)